# Using RabbitMQ when exchange is not available?

Tags: rabbitmq

In MSMQ, you can post a message to a queue on another computer. If that computer is not available, the message will be queued locally, and will be sent once communication is reestablished.

Can I do something like this with RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be achieved with [RabbitMQ Federation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) which will allow you to connect separate RabbitMQ nodes/clusters together. Each server would run RabbitMQ locally (similar to MSMQ running on every server) and the central broker would use federation to collect messages waiting on each server. All publishes will go to the local server and be pulled asynchronously (from the publishing perspective) to the central broker.

Comment: or on the client, but no amqp client i'm aware of implements local queueing (with backing to disk for instance). but one can implement it self..